# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() - Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I need to upload a string to a data bucket. I am following the official [firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) but when I write these two lines:

```js
const storage = getStorage();
const uploadedRef = ref(storage, 'etc/savedExample/');
```

the function logs the error.

Apparently this is because I am invoking firebase before the app is initialized but I have called `admin.InitializeApp()` in my handler file therefore this cannot be true.

Could this be happening because I'm trying to use the same app reference to make querys aswell as upload files to storage?

Code that is meant to work:

```js
//imports:
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
const uploadedRef = ref(storage, 'etc/savedExample/');
uploadString(uploadedRef, "testing").then(() => {
   console.log('Uploaded a raw string!');
}).catch(); //catch a potential rejected promise
```

Comment: Could you please add how you import required packages and how you initialize the app?Are you using Admin SDK on a Firebase Function or trying to use Admin SDK on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client-side web SDK (importing from `firebase` or `firebase/xxx`) is independent of the server-side admin SDK (importing from `firebase-admin` or `firebase-admin/xxx`).

By calling `admin.initializeApp()`, you have prepared the admin SDK for use, but not the client SDK.

To upload a string to Cloud Storage using Node in a Cloud Function, you need to use `admin.storage()` (in the legacy namespaced API) or `getStorage()` (in the new modular API) as covered in the [documentation for the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start).

```js
import { getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';

// assuming initializeApp has already been called by now
const bucket = getStorage().bucket('your-bucket-name');

// bucket is a Bucket object from the Cloud Storage SDK:
// https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html

return bucket.file('etc/savedExample')
  .save("testing")
  .then(() => console.log('uploaded a raw string'))
  .catch((err) -> console.error('failed save', err));
```

See [File#save()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) for the other options for that method.

Comment: This should 100% be shown as an example in the docs. Thank you.